# React: Updated state not reflecting in recursive useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I am incrementing `foo` in a **useCallback** hook called **recursively**. But, the incremented `foo` won't reflect in the callback.

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);

  const recursiveCallback = useCallback(() => {
    // always logs 0
    console.log(foo);

    // incrementing foo
    setFoo(foo + 1);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // recursive call
      recursiveCallback();
    }, 250);
  }, [foo]);

  return <button onClick={recursiveCallback}>Click Me</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the `recursiveCallback` you use in `setTimeout` refers to the one where `foo` had the previous value.

Comment: Hi Andrea, please check the updated question with a note :)

Answer (score 5):

You are having a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `foo===0` value, both in the log and in the setter function, to fix it you need to use [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) and `useEffect` for logging:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);

  const recursiveCallback = useCallback(() => {
    setFoo(prev => prev + 1);

    setTimeout(() => {
      recursiveCallback();
    }, 250);
  }, [foo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(foo);
  }, [foo]);

  return <button onClick={recursiveCallback}>Click Me</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render( < App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, please check the updated question with a note :)

Comment: Again, with the notes, you have closure on `recursiveCallback` inside the timeout, you can't prevent the recursion even though it's within `useCallback`. What you doing seems like https://xyproblem.info/, you should post a question with the actual problem you want to solve and not by trying to fix your solution

Comment: I totally agree with you, sir @Dennis Vash

Comment: @DennisVash understood your point and updated the question with the exact problem.

Comment: @VinaySharma Just post another question... three people already answered for the original one...

Comment: @DennisVash sure. I have reverted this question back to original one.

Comment: @DennisVash could you please add explanation on why updated `foo` won't reflect in the callback and why did you choose `functional update` over `setFoo`? You have mentioned that the callback has closure on `foo === 0`, but why every recursive call has a closure on `0` and not the incremented value of foo such 1, 2, 3... and so on in each subsequent recursive call?

Comment: Well. It doesn't solves the issue, since we will still not get the latest `foo` inside `recursiveCallback` there is no way to stop the recursive call. How do you write the exit condition there?

Comment: In this case why you even need a recursion? Use interval. If you have a specific use case just ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should use `useEffect()` with `[foo]` dependency to see the changes after the state has been set.
2. The function to update `foo` should be a [`Functional update`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to setState
> The function will receive the **previous value**, and **return an updated
> value**

```
    // incrementing foo
    setFoo(previousFoo => previousFoo + 1);
```

**Note:** what happened if you did not choose `functional update`?

Well, if you chose `setFoo(foo + 1);`, the next sate will be 2 only, after that, the state is not changed, `useEffect` with dependency `foo` is also not affected as well.

**In short**, if you need a previous state, you have to use `functional update`.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);

  const recursiveCallback = useCallback(() => {
    // incrementing foo
    //setFoo(foo + 1);
    setFoo(previousFoo => previousFoo + 1);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // recursive call
      recursiveCallback();
    }, 500);
  }, [foo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(foo);
  }, [foo]);
  
  return <button onClick={recursiveCallback}>Click Me</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Could you share more insight why functional update is chosen over `setFoo`?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look at @VinaySharma

Comment: First of all, avoid phrases such as `Ok, it's not a big deal :)` as it doesn’t contribute to the solution and just bloats the comment section. Second, your updated answer `If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value` answers **how** functional update works and not **why** did you choose it.

Comment: Oh no, I have to get back to you right after instead of letting you wait me. That's why `Ok, it's not a big deal :)`. Anyway, I've jut updated my answer, pls check again !!!

Comment: `if you chose setFoo(foo + 1), the next sate will be 2 only` is quite ambiguous as next state should rather be 1 as **foo is initialised as 0**. In the following statement as well `after that, the state is not changed, useEffect with dependency foo is also not affected as well.` it **does not answer *the reason* why state is not changing** and rather stating a fact already known :)

Answer (score 2):

To access the latest value of foo, try changing this line

```
setFoo(foo + 1);
```

to

```
setFoo((foo) => foo + 1);
```

Also, passing `foo` as dependency will update the useCallback hook, so avoid accessing `foo` from outside and use following syntax

```
setState((state) => {
  const newState = { ...state }; 
  // Change State here
  return newState; // return new value
})
```